# In Jenkins - How to use "label" as a parameter in a shell script?

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have a label called **linux**,
which have 4 slaves connected to it.

I want to run a specific command on all those servers using shell script,

for example:

```
for i in {${linux}}
do
   scp ${WORKSPACE}/schemasTST.txt ads_foo@${i}:/DATA/ORACLE_UPGRADE
done
```

Or if we want to simplify it:

How can I get all the serves in this label in a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

I've created a parent job that triggers/call another build ,
And when I'm calling him I pass him the **Label** that I wan't the child job to run on.

So basically the parent job Only triggers the job I need ,
and the child job will run as many times as the number of slaves in that **Label**
(In my case 4 times).

[image]